# Erro na instalação do Wordpress com o plugin PG4WP no servidor

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Estou utilizando [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) com o plugin `PG4WP` para usar o [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql). `Localhost` deu tudo certo. Porém quando migrei para o servidor retorna o seguinte erro na hora de configurar o `wp-config` (`wp-admin/install.php`):

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the PostgreSQL extension
>   which is required by WordPress with PG4WP.

Já alterei o `php.ini` para aceitar [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), mas ainda não está dando certo.

Comment: Em qual host você está colocando seu [tag:wordpress]?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Uolhost

Comment: Realmente acabei de fazer uma pesquisa e só pode ser algo relacionado com as extensões do [tag:postgresql] no [tag:php]

Answer (score 2):

Fiz umas pesquisas e acabei chegando ao seguinte resultado.

> Você não habilitou o módulo do PostgreSQL em seu servidor.
>  Se possuir ele, habilite no php.ini retirando o ';'
>
> Windows:
>
> 1. Edite o php.ini: extension=php_pgsql.dll
>
> Linux:
>
> 1. Instale o módulo: php-pgsql
> 2. Edite o php.ini: extension=pgsql.so
>
> Tutorial:
>  Linux: [Configure PostgreSQL to Work With PHP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Configure_PostgreSQL_to_Work_With_PHP)
>  Windows: [PHP COM POSTGRESQL](http://www.guiadophp.yoonix.com.br/2010/09/15/artigo-php-com-postgresql-%E2%80%93-parte-2/)

Sendo que você já disse que modificou php.ini e está usando o UolHost que e segundo o suporte deles:

> Nosso PHP oferece suporte as base de dados MySQL e SQL Server. Também estão instalados os módulos para acesso a PostgreSQL e Firebird (que podem ser acessados remotamente).
>  
>  OBS: É sempre recomendável acessar as bases na mesma rede local. Se houver problemas de performance em acessar uma base remota, poderemos entrar em contato e desativar o serviço de hospedagem.

Dessa forma te aconselho à procurar diretamente a o suporte da UolHost para conferir suas configurações e se for o caso fazer alguma liberação de algum módulo específico

Comment: Errata: não é Uolhost, mas sim Vps da virtuaserver

Comment: Huuummmm, agora entendi, mas a configuração resolveu o problema?